# This expression is not callable. Type 'String' has no call signatures ts(2349)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have the following class:

```
class User {
    private _email: string;
    
        public get email(): string {
            return this._email;
        }
        public set email(value: string) {
            this._email = value;
        }
    }
      
    
      export {User};
```

I would like to log the user's email, but I can't pass a string parameter throught the function, because it occurs "This expression is not callable.   Type 'String' has no call signatures" problem

```
function App() {

  const user = new User();
  user.email("a@a.hu");
}
export default App;
```

What can I do differently here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a js problem before being Typescript problem.

You need to understand [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

To fix the issue, you can:

```
  const user = new User();
  user.email = "a@a.hu"; // to set the value 
  console.log(user.email) // to read
```